# How to copy a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to copy a file in Node.js?

Example

```
+ /old
|- image.png
+ /new
```

I want to copy image1.png from 'old' to 'new' directory.

This doesn't work.

```
newFile = fs.createWriteStream('./new/image2.png');     
oldFile = fs.createReadStream('./old/image1.png');

oldFile.addListener("data", function(chunk) {
  newFile.write(chunk);
})

oldFile.addListener("close",function() {
  newFile.end();
});
```

Thanks for reply!

Comment: Anything here? http://nodejs.org/api.html#fs-readstream-152 http://nodejs.org/api.html#fs-writestream-154

Comment: @mplungjan I just updated my question.

Comment: new isn't a keyword (can't be used as a variable name)? (not sure)

Answer (score 14):

The preferred way currently:

```
oldFile.pipe(newFile);
```

Comment: and I suppose `oldFile.on('end', function(){ console.log('ready') });`

Answer (score 7):

```
newFile.once('open', function(fd){
    require('util').pump(oldFile, newFile);
});
```

Comment: Does this work for you? I use Node v0.4.0 and `newFile` has zero KB.

Comment: You must wait for the 'open' event of the file to be written. (I added this now).

Comment: a simple `require('util').pump(oldFile, newFile);` worked for me (not waiting for the open event)

Comment: `pump` status was like [that](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nodejs/FwdDQvAf4xM): 'You can expect `util.pump` to go away in the future' as early as Apr'11; it is currently marked 'Experimental' in the docs. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726507/what-is-the-difference-between-util-pumpstreama-streamb-and-streama-pipestre

Comment: You're very outdated, use `pipe`!! See Antony Hatchkins answer.

Comment: **But what about the `mode`, `permissions`, `owner` and `timestamps`?** They're lost. Lost in time. Like my cat.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this job syncronously, just read and then write the file directly:

```
var copyFileSync = function(srcFile, destFile, encoding) {
  var content = fs.readFileSync(srcFile, encoding);
  fs.writeFileSync(destFile, content, encoding);
}
```

Of course, error handling and stuff is always a good idea!

Answer (score -3):

```
fs.rename( './old/image1.png', './new/image2.png', function(err){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  console.log("moved");
});
```

Comment: That's for **moving** (renaming) between the same partition. The OP's asking for **copying** a file.