# Node.js file backup script

Tags: node.js

Does anyone know of a node.js script that periodically runs a backup on a development directory?  (The server I would like to run this on does not allow binaries for security reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) and use the fs module to copy the directory yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/ttezel/anchor - http rsync client/ server, no documentation though, not sure if it carry out a simple sync of one directory to another

Comment: How to copy a file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980243/how-to-copy-a-file