# get uploaded file name/path in node.js

Tags: file, node.js, file-upload

How do I get the name of an uploaded file name/path to manipulate it in node.js? I want move the file from the temp folder to a customer folder.

Comment: tampering filesystem from javascript. impossible in normal settings....

Answer (score 7):

Node.JS doesn't automatically save uploaded files to disk. You'll instead have to read and parse the `multipart/form-data` content yourself via the [request](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverrequest)'s [`data`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_data) and [`end`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_end) events.

Or, you can use a library to do that all for you, such as [`connect`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/)/[`express`](http://expressjs.com/) for its [`bodyParser`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html) or [`multipart`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html) middlewares ([complete example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/multipart/index.js)):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// `bodyParser` includes `multipart`
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(req, res, next){
  // assuming <input type="file" name="upload">

  var path = req.files.upload.path;
  var name = req.files.upload.name;

  // copy...
});
```

Or use [`formidable`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#installation) directly, which `connect` uses for the `multipart` middleware ([complete example](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/example/upload.js)).

And, for the `// copy...` comment, see [How to copy a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4980243).

Comment: I'm confused...everywhere else says 'multipart' is not in bodyParser, but here it says yes?

Comment: @miliu I just haven't updated this answer. At the time this was posted (3 years ago), support for `multipart` was included with the `bodyParser` middleware but has since been removed in favor of other modules dedicated to handling the format, such as [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer) ([mentioned in Express' docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body)). Another significant change since this post is that Express no longer depends upon Connect.

Answer (score -2):

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    var file_name=req.file.filename;
    var file_path=req.file.path;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.